# What specs do I have to check, before replacing laptop battery dead cell?

Tags: battery

Can I replace cells of an old working laptop battery to a new laptop battery which is dead? I have no knowledge about electronics, that's why I am worried.
Specs which are mentioned on battery packs are:
old battery- 6 cells, having an overall rating of 10.8V, 4400mAh, 47.5Wh.
new battery- 4 cells, rating 14.8V, 2620mAh

(note: both laptops are from different manufacturers)

Comment: can you replace the cells of a lithum battery, no, they are sealed and contain hazardious material.  Just replace the battery.  You don't do this to alkaline batteries for the same reason.

Comment: "Can I replace cells of an old working laptop battery" "I have no knowledge about electronics" Based on those two sentences together, no you should not without risk of harming yourself.

Answer (score 2):

This would be a very dangerous thing to attempt: there have been a number of fires reported from batteries in recent years, and these have been due to manufacturing faults either in the batteries or the charging circuits.

What you are proposing is a disaster in the making: there are some things that are just not worth the risk, and trying to reuse batteries in this way is one of them.

My reference on all things battery-related is [here](http://batteryuniversity.com/), but I cannot emphasise too strongly: **DO NOT DO IT**.